# Seeking software which displays (yet) unrelated persons and family trees for overview

Tags: software-recommendations, family-tree, one-name-studies

I am searching for a software, which displays several (yet) unconnected family trees and unrelated persons.

Right now I have 200 people found in old church books with all the same last name over 200-300 years. Somehow they are related to me but in order to find this link I want to display all people and their relationships in one big "display". So there is not just one family tree - there are several small ones and there are persons without a family tree.

These all should be listed on a big display with a vertical timeline. When I add a new person with birthdate it appears vertical at the correct time and maybe in a new column until I connected this person to an existing tree/person.

Is there a software / website platform where this is possible? This must not be necessarily a genealogy software but generating a gedcom file out of it, would be a nice benefit.

Comment: Related but not a duplicate: https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/14125/6485

Answer (score 5):

You could use [Genelines by Progeny Software](https://progenygenealogy.com/Products/Timeline-Charts).

It can produce almost exactly the chart you're asking for in its full descendant chart:

[image]

You would create your input data in another genealogy program and export it to GEDCOM. Then Genelines can read your GEDCOM and produce its descendant report.

Because you're putting together people who are in small families, you'll need to connect any person without a parent to be a child of a fake person named something like: "Church Book People". Then run Genelines descendant report from this fake person, and everyone will show up on a timeline grouped nicely into families as you desire.

The timeline is horizontal rather than vertical, but you'll find that much better for printing and viewing, since reading names horizontal is much easier than reading names vertical.

Comment: Thanks for your post. Yes I will take a look at this. Not 100% what I was wishing for but it looks pretty close. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is not a function of genealogy programs. Would be more fitting for spreadsheets or word documents. But first I would ask if they are already entered into a genealogy program?

I keep about 100+ unknown individuals in my genealogy program (Brother's Keeper). I have an entry titled UNCONNECTED SURNAME, who holds the place of "Father/Grandfather" to some unconnected family groups headed by that surname. Then UNCONNECTED SURNAME also has a child named MYSTERY SURNAME, who is Father of individuals without any family group connections.

But 200 people isn't a lot (in my opinion) to type into a document, that can be easily read, printed, and altered.

Comment: You are right, you may want to do this with such a workaround, but why not asking and showing a demand for something which would be more handy?